# CSS3 Using nth-type and animation delay

Tags: html, css, css-animations

It's possible using nth-type add delay for each image in a list?
in my example I want that each image appears with a different delay, by example, the 1st appears with a .5 delay, the 2nd 1s and so on in each group of 4 images.

Example in this codepen: http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/eJeEmb

EDIT:
More detailed description that i want to do

Iteration 1:

|-- first image of Li moff-1 delayed 0.5|-- first image of Li moff-2 delayed 1s --| ...

Iteration 2:

|-- second image of Li moff-1 delayed 0.5|-- second image of Li moff-2 delayed 1s --| ...

Iteration 3:

|-- third image of Li moff-1 delayed 0.5|-- third image of Li moff-2 delayed 1s --| ...

and so on ...

HTML

```
<ul class="services-images">
          <li class="moff-1">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-03.jpg">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-11.jpg">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-07.jpg">
          </li>
          <li class="moff-2">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-12.jpg">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-02.jpg">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-08.jpg">
          </li>
          <li class="moff-3">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-01.jpg">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-10.jpg">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-06.jpg">
          </li>
          <li class="moff-4">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-05.jpg">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-09.jpg">
            <img src="http://estudiodelacruz.cl/insitu/insitu/images/making-off-04.jpg">
          </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
.services-images, .contact-images {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.services-images img{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.services-images li{
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.services-images img:nth-of-type(1){
  -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 9s linear 9s infinite;
}
.services-images img:nth-of-type(2){
  -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 9s linear 6s infinite;
}
.services-images img:nth-of-type(3){
  -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 9s linear 3s infinite;
}
.services-images img:nth-of-type(4){
  -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 9s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut{

0% { opacity:1; } 
17% { opacity:1; } 
25% { opacity:0; } 
92% { opacity:0; } 
100% { opacity:1; }

}
```

Comment: just use li:nth-of-type instead of img:nth-of-type

Comment: You want each image within the `li` to have a different delay (or) for each image within the same `li` to have same delay but different `li` have different delays?

Comment: @Harry the second option, or each image within the same li to have same delay but different li have different delays. I edited my question for more descriptive idea.

Comment: This seems like something where you would be better of using a preprocessor than writing it by hand, btw.

Comment: You're looking for a very complex animation effect because (a) within an iteration, the images of subsequent `li` should have a higher delay (b) with each iteration, the images across all `li` should move to the next.

Comment: Wow. I just spent 2mins trying to figure out why nothing was happening in the codepen at all. Then I realised that throughout, you've only used `@-webkit-keyframes` and `-webkit-animation:` and never once `@keyframes` nor `animation:` - I'll leave it to your imagination how that goes down in Firefox. Using vendor prefixes as fallbacks is absolutely fine, but please, please, do actually use the standard syntax as well. (Because not all of us are using Chrome / Safari.) Thanks.